# Stopping OnMyLocationChangeListener

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to stop the LocationListener once it has the current location and zoomed to it.

Can you please help a newbie?

Here's my code:

```
@Override
  public void onMyLocationChange(Location location) {

    // Getting latitude of the current location
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    // Getting longitude of the current location
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();

    // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
    LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

    // Showing the current location in Google Map
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));
}
```

Comment: You can remove location listener from location manager `locationManager.removeUpdates(yourLocationListener);`

Comment: Add `locationManager.removeUpdates(this);` after `mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));`

Comment: @Lal That was fast but Eclipse says that it can't resolve locationManager (I have `implement OnMyLocationChangeListener` for my public class) and I'm calling it with `mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this);` @OnCreate

Comment: mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the map location listener to null to turn it off.

```
mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(null);
```

Comment: Probably this and below answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly,the above solution did not work for me,
I had to add:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
```